# How to check my SSD if it's damaged?

Tags: ssd

so i was recording my screen and forgot about it so it recorded 7 hours. The file was 112 GB so i deleted it then i realized that my pc is much slower. It stucks a bit.Also when i deleted the file for a minute my pc freezed and lagged very much for the next 2 minutes then it came "back to normal".Now it lags a bit making noticable.
I think i may damaged my SSD and i was wondering if there is a way to be sure.
So is there any way i can check if my SSD is damaged for the delete of that big file?

Comment: 112GB of blocks is a lot of blocks. Especially if the filesystem needs to go and clear them all.

Comment: What percentage of the drive capacity is this 112GB?  You may have deleted the file at the OS level, but you need to make sure that the SSD also knows that the 112GB should be freed (i.e. the TRIM operation). See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJtsaGgNHXAhXny1QKHRe7CV4QFghmMA0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2F257196%2Fhow-to-check-if-trim-is-enabled-for-your-ssd-and-enable-it-if-it-isnt%2F&usg=AOvVaw0SzRV6hWi1zsJCCd7ajpoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) for HDD/SDD diagnostics. It's a fast and clean tool to get your drive's [S.M.A.R.T. data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) and health.

[image]